# menu link doesnt work on one page of my website

Tags: css, menu

I created a menu with a href="#" links and it works in all pages of my website but on the page "about it doesnt work and i think its because ive also another "href="#"" funcion in another div.... how can i solve this?

MENU:

```
<a class="toggle-menu" href="#">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
  </a>
  <div class="menu-drawer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
...
```

INSIDE OF ABOUT PAGE, I'VE:

```
 
    <li class="About">
<a href="#">
<img width="347" height="500" src="https://files.cargocollective.com/c791011/dino-a-cores.jpg" class="imgvor wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://files.cargocollective.com/c791011/dino-a-cores.jpg 1000w, https://files.cargocollective.com/c791011/dino-a-cores.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" style="width: 347px; height: 500px; left: 402px; top: 280.667px; mix-blend-mode: multiply;">
```

(the class="about" is one funcion that ive, one picture follow my cursor on about section.)

thank you